# project version in .exe-filename

Tags: c++, makefile, codeblocks, auto-versioning

I just tested the auto-versioning plugin and was wondering whether it is possible to put the project's version into the output exe's filename.

So e.g. the output could look like this:

`myProject_0.11.8.exe`

Being able to have the compile-time-date in the filename would be nice aswell:

`myProject_2013_12_16.exe`

Is that possible?

Comment: do you have a resource and manifest file already for your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following to the output filename variable:
[image: output filename location]

add `$(TODAY)` or `$(NOW_)` or `$(NOW_L)`, placing it between the end of the filename and the `.exe` part and you will add the compile date and time (including seconds).

To add the version number you need a few steps (there may be an easier way however I don't know one and would love to hear it:)

First go to `Global Compiler Settings >> #defines` and add `#version = RC_VERSION` thusly:
[image: Global compiler settings]

Then in your project options go to:
[image: output filename with date and version]

I use today and the version number as that means you only get one exe per day and version, whereas using `NOW` gives an exe per minute difference and `NOW_L` gives an exe per second of difference.

### File Link

I have uploaded a sample project at [Test Project](http://programming.dark-arts.tk/testProj.rar) on my website http://www.dark-arts.tk (work in progress).

**NB**: remember to do this for each build you want formatted this way!

Hope this helps, and let me know if you need more info:)

Comment: that's great already :) . So you'd use `.\GettingStarted_$(NOW_L).exe` ?

Comment: I prefer $(NOW) so that you overwrite any compiles done in the same minute, otherwise the file names are unique per second

Comment: is RC_VERSION a define within your project? or is it in the version.h ?

Comment: Would it be possible to always overwrite the 'naked' exe file without the version+date (therefore always being the newest) and having the versioned and dated ones aswell?

Comment: RC_VERSION is in version.h :) You can output the two, one 'naked' exe name and one with extra details by adding another config, duplicate debug and rename the duplicate to Debug_Naked for example then you can select what version to compile, dont know how to make both in one step though:(

Comment: sorry but adding the version to the filename doesn't work for me. Did it work like that on your machine?

Comment: Yep, worked exactly as I copied it into here for me, what version of codeblocks are you using? I am using version 12.11

Comment: Using 12.11 right now. It's a console application and the log says: 'ERROR1: = ..... no such file or directory ||| ERROR2: RC_VERSION .... no such file or directory. I later tried defining with only `version=RC_VERSION` or `$(version)RC_VERSION` those didn't result in errors, but resulted in a blank value within the filename. (I added ERROR1 and ERROR2 to make it more readable, those aren't in the error-log of course)

Comment: did you `#include "version.h"`? as `RC_VERSION` comes from the version file which is created by using autoversioning.

Comment: tried aswell, didn't work. The error seems to appear instantly, once I click compile. Theres no compiling/linking at all before that.

Comment: can you maybe upload a minimal project somewhere so I can test that one and maybe build mine around it?

Comment: I will post one on either later today or tomorrow for you:)

Comment: Apologies for the delay @Wurstbro the file is now uploaded and I have hosted it on my site.  Hope it helps:)

Comment: no problem, and apologies for the delay, had a psu fail which led to some hdds etc dying too

Comment: absolutely no problem :) I just used your project. It compiles fine, but of course after the date the filename ends with `DATE_.exe`. And if I add the define, I get the error again. http://i.imgur.com/0CgOdie.png

Comment: I will try and replicate the same behaviour

Comment: no joy replicating the behaviour of your project, I am working through to see what issues there may be which can cause this however

Comment: Hello, I was just wondering if this answer actually worked for anyone.  I am trying to do the same thing and I get the same result as Wurstbro (two errors saying No such file or directory).  It seems like when it inserts the define into the command line for the compile it gets thrown off by the spaces.  Would it have anything to do with the actual compiler being used?  In my case I am using the GNU GCC Compiler for Tricore v3.4.6.