# Software Version in output file from Code::Blocks IDE

Tags: c, codeblocks, auto-versioning

I would like my output file to include the version number.  I am using the auto-versioning feature in Code::Blocks so I have version.h which includes a couple of defines and variables that relate to the current version/build of the software.

I can see that there is the custom variables tab in build options or global compiler setting where I setup a variable named "version" that I can then use in the output filename.  What I can't figure out is how to have that variable equal any of the defines or variables found in version.h that represent the current version of the software.

If someone can help me with this it would be very appreciated.

I do realize I could also do this with a post build script but if there is a way of doing it with functionality in the IDE it seems easier to me at this point.

This is admittedly a direct duplicate of this questions ([project version in .exe-filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612106/project-version-in-exe-filename)) but it is 5 years old and doesn't seem to work for me (or even the original poster for that matter) so I'm asking it as a new question.

With the answer given in the question above, I get the same results as listed by the original asker in the comments:  when compiling it says no such file or directory.

Thanks

Comment: I am torn between being happy that you did not make an answer there which is actually just a "Me too." and on the other side wondering whether this is really 100% the same question. In which case I am sorry to say that duplicates are off-topic. If you do not highlight anything which makes this different then you will also have no real chance that anyone answers. Why should they?. I am not close-voting or downvoting now, because I really want to give you a chance of being a good example of using StackOveflow the way it is meant. Please point out at leat one special detail.

Comment: Well duplicates are strictly speaking not technically off-topic, they are usually kept as different points of view on the same and to serve as a "look there" pointers. But the point is that they get closed and then cannot be answered, so for you it probably is the same as "off-topic".

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for your input but I'm not sure I follow your concerns exactly.  The question I referencing is asking for the same base question.  However despite being marked as answered, the answer given for that question doesn't work for me or the original poster (I'm not even sure why it was marked as answered).  I mentioned it just so people don't point me to it.  In your opinion what is the correct way to approach asking this question the way StackOverflow is meant?  Thanks for any clarity you can give.

Comment: Edited to put less emphasis on the fact there is a similar question out there.

Comment: If you cannot point out a difference or at least give a fresh angle to the question, then you should comment on the original question. Maybe pointing out your doubts about the accepted answer can provoke the answerer to improve. Or the asker can explain why/how the accepted answer helped them. An expensive way would be to put a bounty on the other question, with an explanation why the existing answer cannot earn the bounty.

Comment: Okay, so even if it's 5 years old I should try to resurrect it by commenting on it as a first step.  Okay I will try that.  Thanks.